# unable to load nvidia-drm kernel module

Tags: installation, gpu, nvidia, fedora

I am following this [webpage](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/) to install nvidia GPU drivers in my fedora 34 64 bit system but it prompts me with an error of unable to load nvidia-drm kernel module while installing. The nvidia driver I used is Quadro RTX 4000 version, 470.74

The log during installation is here.
https://pastebin.com/5GbYcMgp `log for nvidia fedora installation`

Help of any sort will be appreciated!

Comment: It could be a version mismatch with `gcc`, so a downgrade might sort things out. Why can't you use the ones provided by the 3rd party repos/RPM Fusion, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @telometto thank you very much for your reply. I am installing from RPM Fusion now but as my computer belongs to the university, it has some permission issue that I already have asked help with IT department and will let you know how it goes for me.

Comment: You've probably figured something out by now. Nonetheless... On other distributions, there are instructions to add `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` in _/etc/default/grub_. That won't fix the installer problem, but it's nice to know in case you're trying to use Wayland, which (for now) requires the drm module.